# C++ self resolving class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-deduction

I am facing an issue of creating a wrapper for a kind of complicated data structure. Let's say I have messages which have some features which are shared, and absolutely different "detail" kind of fields, which are to be stored in the same struct. I have created two classes, one of them is "Base" of structure and the second is handling additional data inside of those "special" fields. Let me show a code that I am working on.

Here is a `Message.hxx`:

```cpp
namespace mgm = meta::game::message;

namespace shared::common::message
{
    class Message
    {
        std::unique_ptr<mgm::Message> mp_data;

    public:
        [[nodiscard]] std::uint64_t getMessageId() { return mp_data->id(); }

        [[nodiscard]] std::uint8_t getSender() { return mp_data->sender(); }
        [[nodiscard]] std::uint8_t getRecipient() { return mp_data->recipient(); }

        [[nodiscard]] std::string getInfo() { return mp_data->info()->str(); }

        [[nodiscard]] std::uint64_t getServerTimeStamp() { return mp_data->server_time_stamp(); }
    };
}

namespace scm = shared::common::message;
```

Here is the "detail" class which is not really implemented, but it is not important `SimpleMessage.hxx`:

```cpp
namespace shared::common::message
{
    class SimpleMessage
        : public Message
    {

    };
}
```

I was thinking,

> Hey maybe I will add template type deduction/specialization! It sounds like a great idea!

`MessageResolver.hxx`

```cpp
namespace
{
    namespace mgm = meta::game::message;
}

namespace shared::common::message
{
    class Message;
    class SimpleMessage;

    template<mgm::Request RESPONSE_TYPE, mgm::Response REQUEST_TYPE>
    class MessageResolver : std::false_type {};

    template<>
    struct MessageResolver<mgm::Request::Request_SimpleRequest, mgm::Response_SimpleResponse>
    {
        SimpleMessage* operator ()(Message* message)
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<SimpleMessage*>(message);
        }
    };
}
```

and add code to my `Message.hxx` class...

```cpp
namespace mgm = meta::game::message;

namespace shared::common::message
{
    class Message
    {
        std::unique_ptr<mgm::Message> mp_data;

    public:
        [[nodiscard]] std::uint64_t getMessageId() { return mp_data->id(); }

        [[nodiscard]] std::uint8_t getSender() { return mp_data->sender(); }
        [[nodiscard]] std::uint8_t getRecipient() { return mp_data->recipient(); }

        [[nodiscard]] std::string getInfo() { return mp_data->info()->str(); }

        [[nodiscard]] std::uint64_t getServerTimeStamp() { return mp_data->server_time_stamp(); }



        [[nodiscard]] decltype(MessageResolver<req,resp>()) get() { return MessageResolver<req,resp>(); };


    };
}

namespace scm = shared::common::message;
```

and at this point, my dreams crumbled. I can't initialize this statement with non-`constexpr` types...

My desired effect is, to get access to get a self-resolving class. Is this possible? I came here for the Gods of StackOverflow to assist, with my journey to find the answers.

Comment: Maybe [CRTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) can assist you.

Comment: Oh, hello @AmirKirsh! Yes I do thought about it, although I really cannot wrap my head around it. It's like I have an idea how, but then it just does not seem to work. I do created `Message` and `MessageT` classes, but I just can't find a way to make it work. Don't get me wrong, It does work, but user anyway have to template declare what he is using, which is in my case not really solving an issue. Why? Because If I want user to know what message is, I would just let him static/reinterpret cast it to what it needs to be (this is current solution). Could you maybe help me figure out baseline?